# Angular : Align mat tooltip to left on a row using fxflex

Tags: css, angular, tooltip

I have a row with fxflex being used and I am trying to display the tooltip. But the problem is that I don't want to display the tooltip at the center for a single large wide row. Rather, I would want to display the tooltip right under the text, which is on the left that single wide row. So, is there a way to move the tooltip to the left, so that the text in the row and the tooltip are on the left side?

Here is how it looks now :

`<span fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center" [matTooltip]="selectedPage.title">{{selectedPage.title}}</span>`

Here is a screenshot after using matToolTipPosition property :

`<span fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center"  [matTooltipPosition]="'left'" [matTooltip]="selectedPage.title">{{selectedPage.title}}</span>`

[image]

should I go for a matTooltipClass for this or some other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

use `matTooltipPosition`option

```
<span fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center"  matTooltipPosition="below" [matTooltip]="selectedPage.title">{{selectedPage.title}}</span>
```

Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples

Comment: Yes, I used it and it went something like this `[matTooltipPosition]="'left'"`. But the tooltip got moved towards the end of the row. No idea why.

Comment: Please attach the screen shot

Comment: Now, I have updated my answer. Please try it.

Comment: Please update the full code(only toolbar menu)